# ASP.NET MVC template with webgrid instead of table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, webgrid, view-templates

Is there a Asp.net MVC View Template that uses WebGrid instead of a `<table>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should recommend you to set up a T4 template that generates the code that you want for your MVC View Template. Its pretty easy, have a look at this guide and you should get up and going... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291528.aspx

> Microsoft Visual Studio includes a code generation engine known as T4
>   (which is short for Text Template Transformation Toolkit). You’ve
>   probably already used T4 templates in Visual Studio without even
>   knowing they were working behind the scenes.